# nodejs - Can't get paypal-ipn to work. Paypal keeps returning "INVALID"

Tags: node.js, paypal, paypal-ipn

I'm trying to use the nodejs module paypal-ipn to verify a payment made to paypal.

I pass into the verify method data in the following format...

```
{ tx: '60R52218GS3878125',
  st: 'Completed',
  amt: '0.01',
  cc: 'GBP',
  cm: '',
  item_number: '' }
```

Everytime I use it I keep getting "INVALID" as the response back from Paypal.

Comment: Are those all of the fields/values you receive from the IPN?

Comment: Note if you use sandbox it will always return INVALID. At least it dies to me. The same code return INVALID with sandbox and VERIFIED on live transaction.

Answer (score 0):

What are you posting back to Paypal? According to the paragraph "A Sample IPN Message and Response" in https://cms.paypal.com/uk/cgi-bin/?cmd=_render-content&content_ID=developer/e_howto_admin_IPNIntro you need to POST the *very same string* back that you received. I.e.

> PayPal sends a message, similar to the following one, for a $19.95
>   purchase made by Express Checkout:
>
> mc_gross=19.95&protection_eligibility=Eligible&address_status=confirmed&payer_id=LPLWNMTBWMFAY&tax=0.00&address_street=1+Main+St&payment_date=20%3A12%3A59+Jan+13%2C+2009+PST&payment_status=Completed&charset=windows-1252&address_zip=95131&first_name=Test&mc_fee=0.88&address_country_code=US&address_name=Test+User&notify_version=2.6&custom=&payer_status=verified&address_country=United+States&address_city=San+Jose&quantity=1&verify_sign=AtkOfCXbDm2hu0ZELryHFjY-Vb7PAUvS6nMXgysbElEn9v-1XcmSoGtf&payer_email=gpmac_1231902590_per%40paypal.com&txn_id=61E67681CH3238416&payment_type=instant&last_name=User&address_state=CA&receiver_email=gpmac_1231902686_biz%40paypal.com&payment_fee=0.88&receiver_id=S8XGHLYDW9T3S&txn_type=express_checkout&item_name=&mc_currency=USD&item_number=&residence_country=US&test_ipn=1&handling_amount=0.00&transaction_subject=&payment_gross=19.95&shipping=0.00
>
> Before you can trust the contents of the message, you must first
>   verify that the message came from PayPal. To verify the message, you
>   must send back the contents in the exact order they were received and
>   precede it with the command _notify-validate, as follows:
>
> https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr?cmd=_notify-validate&mc_gross=19.95&protection_eligibility=Eligible&address_status=confirmed&payer_id=LPLWNMTBWMFAY&tax=0.00&...&payment_gross=19.95&shipping=0.00

So: Do not alter the data that you received before trying to verify.